# Failed to connect SourceTree to AWS CodeCommit

Tags: git, macos, amazon-web-services, atlassian-sourcetree, aws-codecommit

I'm using Atlassian's SourceTree to work with git on Mac OS, and choose AWS CodeCommit as the remote hosting server.

Following these [steps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html) for HTTPs connection between AWS and my local repo,

here's how my `git config --global --edit` looks like:

[image]

Then try to clone a created empty repo from AWS to SourceTree:
[image]

And I get error printed out:

> abort: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden aws --profile default codecommit
>   credential-helper $@ get: aws: command not found fatal: unable to
>   access
>   'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-git-repo/':
>   The requested URL returned error: 403

**UPDATE**

Tried the answer provided by @Steffen Opel and got more like:

[image]

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, but given AWS CodeCommit facilitates a [credential helper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html#setting-up-https-unixes-credential-helper) too and the error being`command not found`, I would assume you are affected by the same issue outlined in the SourceTree Knowledge Base article [Credential helpers "git: 'credential-osxkeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'."](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=390496445):

> The error [...] occurs because Git calls this helper and cannot find
>   it meaning it has been defined and yet not found on the PATH. In terms
>   of SourceTree as of version 1.6.3 this is nothing to worry about.
>   There's two ways to stop this from happening.
>
> 1. Not recommended, but if you're solely using SourceTree for
>      everything you could remove the 'credential' setting from the
>      /usr/local/git/etc/gitconfig config. This is a quick and easy
>      method, but it does mean operations at the terminal may not be able
>      to authenticate.
> 2. Recommended, create a symlink between
>      git-credential-osxkeychain in the SourceTree app resources and your
>      local git install.
>
>    `ln -s /usr/local/git/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain
>      /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/git_local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain`

Of course, since AWS CodeCommit requires the credential helper to be in place, only solution 2 is conceptually applicable for your scenario and you need to adjust the link source and targets as appropriate for the CodeCommit credential helper.

Comment: not sure if this helps, but I use Tower 2.  I was getting the same error.  I went to the git config settings and told Tower to use the git i installed with brew, /usr/local/bin/git (v2.6.3) and it started working for me.

Answer (score 7):

I just found this answer here (https://geekprotem.com/2015/07/10/aws-codecommit-with-sourcetree/)

After following the setup steps for AWS CLI on Amazon's website, the final step to get this to work was editing my repository's config file in SourceTree to include the following:

```
[credential]
helper = /usr/local/bin/aws codecommit credential-helper $@
UseHttpPath = true
```

Comment: Thanks. For Windows, I had to put `helper = "C:/Progra~1/Amazon/AWSCLI/aws.exe" codecommit credential-helper $@`. Hope it helps to anyone.

Comment: @DiegoJancic your comment helped me to solve this issue thanks.

Answer (score 1):

seems about right. the "command not found" is the problem.
I would say that aws is not in the path, and when the credential helper tries to help it cannot find it. double check it's in the path by doing `which aws`

Comment: it's `usr/local/bin/aws`, btw I tried to clone the remote repo to my local machine with command line tool and added it to SourceTree manually, it worked fine and I succeeded to push files to AWS in SourceTree. What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

if you installed aws cli from homebrew (instead of pkg) , and you have it in .gitconfig credential without path you can do this simple fix, link to the pkg install path, tested and working on Sourctree.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/aws /usr/local/bin/aws
```